# Turning enhanced for loop into a normal for loop

Tags: java, arrays

I need to turn this piece of code into a normal for loop for what I'm working on and I am stuck.

```
for(int number : input) {
   queue.add(number);
   }
```

I have tried -

```
for(int i = 0;<input.length;i++){
    queue.add(input);
  }
```

I am not very familiar with enhance for loops so I am not sure where to go from there.

This is my entire code so far -

```
class Solution {
    public int[] sortArray(int[] input) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for(int number : input) {
            queue.add(number);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            input[i] = queue.poll();
        }
        return input;
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `queue.add(input)` with `queue.add(input[i])`. The statement, `queue.add(input)` will add the whole of the array, `input` to `queue`.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you're trying to add the entire array to queue. You have to append the single element at `i` index in `input` instead.

This would work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    queue.add(input[i]);
}
```